# Is there any way to turn off a particular scrolling behaviour?

Tags: css

I'm not sure that this is a wordpress behaviour, but it seems to be.

On certain blogs, when I scroll using either arrow keys or trackpad, it scrolls in a much jumpier way than the default behaviour. For example, one tap of the arrow key will jump much more than it normally would. Alternatively, on the trackpad it either scrolls a very small amount or a very large amount, depending on how rapidly I swipe, instead of the usual amount on most website.

I find this incredibly frustrating, because it makes certain websites differ in behaviour from every other one, and as such is harder to control. I'm assuming that this is a CSS or wordpress issue, but I'm not quite sure, as it is a little difficult to google.

Is there any way to turn this off?

Comment: I should note that this is one blog that exhibits the behaviour in question: http://foodperestroika.com/

Comment: I doubt this is WordPress Core. It is probably a theme or plugin, or theme/plugin combination. Have you tried with a bundled theme and no plugins? More than likely Javascript is at fault... my guess anyway.